# Where is the macOS .config file?

Tags: macos, linux-kernel, config

I was looking for how to compile my own Linux 5.1 kernel and noticed that the `.config` file is stored in `/boot/config-$(uname -r)`.

I know that macOS is Unix-based, but still, I was wondering to get my hands on the `.config` file of macOS and explore the system structure...

Comment: This question makes no sense.  **macOS is not Linux**, so perhaps your question is improperly tagged.  Nor is macOS as installed on a Mac open source, though some of it is available as the Darwin project, which is.   If you were trying to *build Linux on a Mac* the config file would be in a prepared source tree (ie after make defconfig or whatever), though note there are some unique setup requirements to make that kind of cross compilation work.

Comment: config is Linux configuration file for kernel building. MacOs is: 1- not Linux, 2- source is not published (so no way to compile it). 3- the meaning of line in config is very Linux (and version dependent), for "monolitic kernels", where drivers should be compiled at same time of kernel.